# Is it possible to load an .so library from unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have built a library using android ndk and I'm wondering if I can load it from my Unity project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  See the documentation on [developing Android plugins](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html).

Copy your .so to the Plugins/Android folder, and declare its functions in your Unity scripts like so:

```
[DllImport ("PluginName")]
public static extern float FooPluginFunction ();
```

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on this? I've got one Android Project that compiles this .so and I want my unity project (another apk) to call functions from it. So on java I'd load the library by using "System.loadLibrary("com_industrycorp_sparkterminalclientndk_ClientNDKLib")", do I use that same string inside [DllImport ("com_industrycorp...")]?

Comment: I just use DllImport once and then copy the function signatures for each function I want to use from that library?

Comment: To be clear I have 2 different APKs, one is implementing the native functions and exposing them through the .so. The other is loading the .so and calling it's functions which I hope will still be linked to the first APK I mentioned and call functions off of it.

Comment: The code I posted is creating method signatures as part of a class which is basically a wrapper for your library.  Its a static method, so you can do:

**MyPluginWrapper.FooPluginFunction();**

wherever you need to call that function in your libarary.

Comment: The [DllImport] directive, by the way, is telling the compiler that the external function declared in the next line points to a function in the plugin you named.